# How to move a image View left and right in android development

Tags: android, ide

I am very new to Android Development, and I am trying to develop a game. In this game, I will require a Imageview to move left and right when pressed by a button. My current IDE that I am using is "Android Studio". So I have done research but am not finding any answers. My current code is

```
package com.example.turtle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button left, right ;
ImageView turtle ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bl);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.br);
    turtle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVT);
    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

So yeah, As you can see I set up an OnClcikListener but I don't know what goes under it. I heard I can lessen a position, but how would I do that ? Like what is the code to lessen a position ? Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the layout file activity_main?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865118/simple-thread-issue-with-android-animation/16865270#comment24367783_16865270. use a handler move the image with a delay

Comment: Plz check my feedback in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955221/how-to-move-a-image-view-left-and-right-in-android-development-2/16955916#16955916

Answer (score 2):

At least for the newer Android studio this is how I would do it.

In your xml text code,(in your design/layout page go on the bottom and click text)

`<Button
        android:onClick="LeftBonClick"
        (plus any additional xml code you have for this button.)
/>`

And then on you java code...

```
public void LeftBonClick(View view) {
     turtle.setX(turtle.getX() - 2); //<<code depending on your preference and what layout your turtle is in.
     //add any code you want to happen here, when the left button is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the new parameteres for your ImageView with the following code inside onClick() method:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(50,50, 0,0);
// OR
params.topMargin= 50;
turtle.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Marek, if you mean type it like this

http://i.imgur.com/z2nplJG.png

Then it didn't work because I have errors, can you see what I did wrong ? If I entered the code in the right place ? Or what I can do to fix the errors ? Thanks