# How to move a image View left and right in android development (2)

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I have asked this before but no answers that worked for me.

[How to move a image View left and right in android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952058/how-to-move-a-image-view-left-and-right-in-android-development?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Is it your requirement to move image view with button press? or touch is also fine for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865118/simple-thread-issue-with-android-animation/16865270#comment24367783_16865270. check this might help you. You should explain your problem clearly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move a image View left and right in android development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952058/how-to-move-a-image-view-left-and-right-in-android-development)

Comment: I can offer some advice.  Learn the basics first by completing "Hello World" tutorials and *understanding* how they work.  Then learn how to write good questions.  This is not a good question.  You should also work with your existing question rather than open a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code:

In main.xml:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Left"
    android:onClick="onClickLeft"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Right"
    android:onClick="onClickRight"/>
```

And then in the .java file put this code:

```
public void onClickLeft(View view){
    ImageView t = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.gravity=3;

        t.setLayoutParams(params);
}

public void onClickRight(View view){
    ImageView t = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.gravity=5;

        t.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I just did EXACTLY that, and I got NO errors at all, so I was pretty happy but when I ran the emulator, and left and the right button do absolutely nothing. Also after a few clicks, my emulator crashes. What should I do ?

Comment: wait no, my emulator doesnt crash, my program crashes.

Comment: I tried on my cell phone. It is working fine. Post you code let me run and check on my phone.

Comment: I hope you are using Linear Layout.

Comment: I haha, I was using relative. Okay I switched to Linear, and I ran the code, It worked but not really what I wanted. It bring the image view from the left side ALL the way to the right side in one click rather then slowly bringing it there. For example, I wanted to make it like a platform game, such as mario ? So I would need the image view to slowly move to one side to another, rather then entirely all at the same time.

Comment: Do you know how to do that ? make it go slowly ?

Comment: the following thread can give you good idea on how to do the same. It involves animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865118/simple-thread-issue-with-android-animation/16865270#comment24367783_16865270

Comment: Also, would suggest you to give clear description of what you want to achieve. You should mention its about animating the slow movement of the object left/right.

Comment: I tried looking at the thread you sent me, but I dont really understant it. Like I dont understand which parts is related to my game, and which parts is unrelated to my game.